# 3D Stream function in fluid mechanics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, potential, vector-fields, flow

The 3D stream function ${\bf \Psi}$ for a steady flow field can be defined as:
$\rho{\bf u}={\bf \nabla}\times {\bf \Psi}$.

Where, ${\bf u}$ = velocity, $\rho$ = density.

Now, this ${\bf \Psi}$ can be in turn represented as:  ${\bf \Psi}=\chi{\bf \nabla}\psi $. Where, $\chi$ and $\psi$ are stream surfaces. What is the physical significance of $\chi$ and $\psi$?

Comment: The author has directly defined the stream function as  **ψ** = *χ* grad *ψ*. I am having trouble understanding why he has defined stream it in this manner. Specifically, I cannot figure out intuition behind that definition?

Comment: Which author? Which page?

Comment: Are you comfortable with the 2D version of this, where ##chi## is a constant?  Does that make sense to you from the standpoint of physical interpretation?

Comment: You should mention the book's name. As far as I know, if $\psi$ is the scalar stream-function for 2d or axisymmetric flow, then velocity field is given by the curl of the vector $[0,0,\psi]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The 3D [stream function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function) ${\bf \Psi}$ exists such that $\rho{\bf u}={\bf \nabla}\times {\bf \Psi}$ in a simply connected region for an [incompressible flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompressible_flow) ${\bf \nabla}\cdot(\rho{\bf u})=0$ due to [Poincare Lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoincaresLemma.html).
2. Any 3D vector field ${\bf \Psi}={\bf \nabla}\varphi + \chi{\bf \nabla}\psi $ can be represented by 3 scalar [Clebsch potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch_representation).
3. We can remove the $\varphi$ potential due to the gauge symmetry ${\bf \Psi}\to{\bf \Psi}+{\bf \nabla}\varphi$.
4. The flow $\rho{\bf u}={\bf \nabla}\chi \times  {\bf \nabla}\psi$ is along the 1D intersection of the two 2D [equipotential surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipotential) for $\chi$ and $\psi$.
5. $(\chi,\psi)$ is a [canonical pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_coordinates): The flow is invariant under canonical transformations $(\chi,\psi)\to (\chi^{\prime},\psi^{\prime})$.

Comment: +1 Great answer. I just realized that a divergence-free vector field allows it to be written as curl of another vector field.